# Python - I am trying to random call a function but keep getting error

Tags: python

I am trying to call any of the functions listed in the **init** method, from the mathsum method but keep getting an error as follows:

> 'XXX' object has no attribute 'operator'.

```
 class Math(object):
        "Main class to generate different math sums based on operator and difficulty levels"

        def __init__(self):
            self.operator = [
                addition,
                subtraction,
                multiplication,
                division
                ])

        def addition(self, a, b): return ('addition', '+', a+b)

        def subtraction(self, a, b): return ('subtraction', '-', a-c)

        def mutliplication(self, a, b): return ('multiplication', '*', a*c)

        def division(self, a, b): return ('division', '/', a/c)

        def mathsum(self, difficulty):
            """Function that generates random operator and math sum checks against your answer"""
            print self.operator
```

Please help

Comment: do you have that extra `)` after `self.operator = [...]` in your init block?  That should raise a syntax error.  Also, how are you instantiating this `Math` class?

Comment: No – this is *not* the error you’re getting with the above code.

Comment: There are a few problems. In addition to the wayward `)` in `__init__` and the missig `self.` in front of the array elements for `operator`, some of your operations declar `a, b` as parameters when they use `a` and `c`. If I fix those two problems, calling something like `MyMath().addition(2, 3)` works. It's not clear what `mathsum` is supposed to do, though.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a couple of self.s:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.operator = [
        self.addition,
        self.subtraction,
        self.multiplication,
        self.division
        ]
```

Also, note that you misspelled *multiplication* in the function definition.

Comment: I'll be more clear next time.  First time posting.  Thank you though.  That solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't vote to close. I guess you can still "accept" my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
class MyMath(object):
    """Main class to generate different math sums based on operator and difficulty levels"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.operator = [ self.addition, self.subtraction, self.multiplication, self.division ]

    def addition(self, a, b):
        return ('addition', '+', a+b)

    def subtraction(self, a, b):
        return ('subtraction', '-', a-b)

    def multiplication(self, a, b):
        return ('multiplication', '*', a*b)

    def division(self, a, b):
        return ('division', '/', a/b)

    def mathsum(self, difficulty, a, b):
        """Function that generates random operator and math sum checks against your answer"""
        print self.operator
```

Calling this:

```
MyMath().addition(2, 3)
```

Gives this:

```
('addition', '+', 5)
```

I'm not sure what you are expecting in terms of calling sequence and results, but this does not generate an error if declared and called as above.